# functional hibernate.cfg.xml for hibernate 4

Tags: hibernate

does anybody have a functional cfg file example for hibernate 4 ? 
All the reference i can find online is for less than v4 and that doesn't work.  i tried pasting the contents of my file here but this site removes the hibernate-configuration tag.

so here is what comes out:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/">

<hibernate-configuration xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration">

  <session-factory> 

    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property> 
    <!-- Assume test is the database name --> 
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/foampile</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property> 
    <!-- List of XML mapping files --> 

    <mapping resource="SiteRecord.hbm.xml"/>

  </session-factory> 

</hibernate-configuration>
```

once I change to

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

i get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 63; Attribute "xmlns" must be declared for element type "hibernate-configuration".
```

BUT xmlns IS specified (xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration")

IS THIS A BUG IN HIBERNATE 4.1 ???

Comment: seems like the problem is with !DOCTYPE but i don't know what to set it to.  if i set it to the one that has reference to v3 DTD, it fails parsing again and if i do not include the doctype, it complains that hibernate-configuration is missing the xmlns attribute ...  I AM EXTREMELY FRUSTRATED WITH THIS, WASTED THE LAST 2 HRS

Comment: the Hibernate 4 online doc shows an example without any DOCTYPE.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch01.html#d5e83

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: No.  I just reverted to using H3 cause I could get that to work...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I was able to get it to work by just removing all the attributes from hibernate-configuration, despite what the documentation and error messages say :)  So in the end, I have this for my DOCTYPE:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

and then I just have:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
....
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

... for what it's worth, I ended up having IntelliJ created the stub file, just to get a start on it (for hibernate 4.1):

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```