# What doctype to use for hibernate 4

Tags: hibernate

My question is essentially the same as this:
[functional hibernate.cfg.xml for hibernate 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206721/functional-hibernate-cfg-xml-for-hibernate-4)
but I'm not able to post on that because I don't have enough reputation points, and that one hasn't been answered yet.

I'm using Hibernate 4.3.4 with a hibernate.cfg.xml file (in Tomcat 6.0.39).  At the top of the .xml file, I have:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD     3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

When I try to create the configuration, I get the following error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute "xmlns" must be declared for element type "hibernate-configuration"
```

After googling around, it seemed like something might be wrong with my DOCTYPE, and in the hibernate documentation I have, the example .cfg.xml file doesn't have a DOCTYPE at all, so I tried removing it, but then I get this error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document is invalid: no grammar found
```

I then tried looking to see how I could turn off the validation that is causing this, but I'd really rather just do it the right way.  Does anyone have a functional hibernate.cfg.xml file for hibernate version 4, or perhaps know what dumb thing I've done wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that if I just remove everything from , it works.  I'd rather have it match the actual documentation which doesn't have a DOCTYPE, but for now, I'll leave it like this since it's working.